# How to configure Desktop Notification in Conkeror browser?

Tags: conkeror

How can I enable Desktop Notification for web apps (Slack, for example)?

I didn't find anything about this on Conkeror Wiki, Mailling List or Google :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To add desktop notification for Conkeror, you need to use the XPCOM nsIPermissionManager interface, for example

```
var permissionManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/permissionmanager;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPermissionManager);

permissionManager.add(
    make_uri("http://www.messenger.com/"),
    "desktop-notification",
    Components.interfaces.nsIPermissionManager.ALLOW_ACTION
  );
```